# Alloy Forms Pattern?

Tags: javascript, forms, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

In working with Titanium's Alloy framework, the models are using Backbone.js. I'm new to both Backbone.js and Alloy.

I'm familiar with ExtJS however, and in ExtJS, you can create a form, and then say something like:

```
form.loadRecord(record);       // where record is an instance of a model
```

and then

```
form.getRecord(record);        // When you're saving the form, get the record
var vals = form.getValues();   // And then get the values from the form that the user changed
record.setValues(vals);        // Update your record with whatever values the user changed.
```

So my question is, what is the pattern for forms in Alloy? Or is there not one?

I could easily make my own functions, however I'm running into an issue where the app crashes when trying to bind a model to a form object like this:

```
that.model = model;             // where model was passed in to the form.loadRecord function.
```